# Is loading JSP into div of another JSP is correct procedure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I loaded the jsp in div using this code.

```
 $("#divone").load("/home.jsp");
```

It is working fine, the problem is the jquery library is loaded two times, that causing problems like unbinding events, dialog box open and close..

Is this correct approach? and how to avoid loading two jquery libraries.

Comment: remove the script tag to jquery from home.jsp ?

Comment: it showing error jquery undefined...